# How to communicate Java front-end with java spring boot back-end

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I'm developing a full-stack univerity project: this is a management system for resturant. The front end is based on JavaFX and Java; I used MVC pattern for the code's structure. The back end is based on Java SpringBoot, with "PostgreSQL Driver", "Spring Data JPA" and "Spring Web" dependencies for the project.
In the front end i have a section where i have to take all plate's categories (like "Appetizers", for example) and to do that i have to call a method inside backend, that will execute the query. I don't know how to do that, i read online that Amplify is a possibility, but honestly i want to know if it is the best way to do that.